# libxmljs@0.19.10 install issue with node 12.19.1

Tags: node.js, libxml-js

Build error for installing libxmljs@0.19.10 for node 12 as shown below

[build error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETbrn.png)

I am stuck on this since yesterday, any help would be appreciated.

I tried few old versions as well but nothing works.

Comment: Did you try to use newer versions of node,js?

Comment: @Anatoly Server I am trying to deploy my changes to has node 12 and cannot be updated for some other reason. It works on my local though with node 14

Comment: Can you try Node,js 12 using nvm locally?